# Adding two lists with different length to a Dictionary then to a Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, list

I have two lists with different length such as below:

```
list1 = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']
list2 = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [1, 8, 4, 3], [22, 35, 32], [65], [2, 45, 55]]
```

and I have a Dataframe as the following with 6 rows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Alex', 33, 'Male'], [Marly, 28, 'Female'], [Charlie, 30, 'Female'], ['Mimi', 37, 'Female'], ['James', 44, 'Male'], ['Jone', 25, 'Male']], columns=['Name', 'Age', 'Gender'])

|name   |age|Gender|
|:------|:--|:-----|
|Alex   |33 |Male  |
|Marly  |28 |Female|
|Charlie|30 |Female|
|Mimi   |37 |Female|
|James  |44 |Male  |
|Jone   |25 |Male  |
```

I want to concat list1 as columns and list2 as rows as bellow:

```
|name   |age|Gender|col1|col2|col3|col4|
|:------|:--|:-----|:---|:---|:---|:---|
|Alex   |33 |Male  |1   |2   |3   |0   |
|Marly  |28 |Female|2   |3   |0   |0   |
|Charlie|30 |Female|1   |8   |4   |3   |
|Mimi   |37 |Female|22  |35  |32  |0   |
|James  |44 |Male  |65  |0   |0   |0   |
|Jone   |25 |Male  |2   |45  |55  |0   |
```

However, list1 and list2 are updated **inside a loop** and added to the Dataframe, so **I want to do that using dictionary or any other efficient way** as I am dealing with large number columns and once I tried to add the columns using

```
df[list1] = pd.DataFrame(list2, index=df.index)
```

I got Performance warning DataFrame is highly fragmented.

Comment: It'd help if you provided a [reproducible pandas example](/q/20109391/4518341)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

out = pd.concat(
    [
        df,
        pd.DataFrame(
            [dict(zip(list1, vals)) for vals in zip(*zip_longest(*list2, fillvalue=0))]
        ),
    ],
    axis=1,
)


print(out)
```

Prints:

```
      name  age  Gender  col1  col2  col3  col4
0     Alex   33    Male     1     2     3     0
1    Marly   28  Female     2     3     0     0
2  Charlie   30  Female     1     8     4     3
3     Mimi   37  Female    22    35    32     0
4    James   44    Male    65     0     0     0
5     Jone   25    Male     2    45    55     0
```